# In android ,sdk and jdk are not detected

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am developing an android application. I'm not sure what happened, but suddenly all the sdk packages are not being read by gradle compiler and the package classes are underlined red including jdk package classes. The sdk and jdk are installed and path correctly given. What could the error be? Thanks.